# Firebase Cloud Function doesn't trigger

Tags: typescript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to write a Firebase Cloud Function which sends a user a notification whenever I answer their suggestion. Here's my database structure:

```
suggestions
    |_________ 3F13512E-C302-4D90-A829-6605C7DB33C9 (Device Id as string) 
                       |_______ a28JBV86Csiow9h7Vdr4 (random string) 
                                       |________ doc
                                                  |_______ suggestion = "some text..."
                                                  |_______ senderToken = the token of the sender
                                                  |_______ answer = ""
```

Here's the code I've written (in typescript):

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
admin.initializeApp()
const messagingAdmin = admin.messaging()
const db = admin.firestore()

export const onAnswerUpdate = functions.region('europe-west1').database
.ref('/suggestions/{deviceId}/{randomId}/doc')
.onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {
   const deviceId = context.params.deviceId
   const randomId = context.params.randomId
   console.log(`New answer from detected. Will attempt to send user a notification.`)

   const newData = snapshot.after.val()
   const token = newData.senderToken
   const suggestion = newData.suggestion
   const answer = newData.answer

   console.log(`Sending notification: body = myBody: ${answer}, ${suggestion}`)

   //Generate the payload
   const payload = {
      notification: {
          title: 'myTitle',
          body: `myBody: ${answer}, ${suggestion}`
      },
      data: { }
  };

   //Send the message
   messagingAdmin.sendToDevice(token, payload)
   .then(function (response) {
      console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error sending message:", error);
  })
  return null
})
```

After deploying the function, I can see it in the console, but whenever I update the "answer" field, nothing happens. I don't see anything in the log except for

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"myemail@gmail.com"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.CreateFunction","resourceName":"projects/project-name/locations/europe-west1/functions/onAnswerUpdate"}
```

Also, the "Usage" tab says 0 invocations, and I don't get any errors in the "health" tab.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.